# constrained convolution layer

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I would like to create a custom convolution layer in which, after each back-propagation, the weights of my kernel matrix should be in a specific format: the central value must be -1, and the sum of the rest must be 1.

[image]

I want to implement it in Pytorch.

Comment: Do you want a way to change the weights when a layer is defined as:
layer = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, (3, 3))

Comment: I would like each kernel to have its weight translated into the normalized format that I would like after it has been updated. It should take place during the training process.